# When redirecting from http to https, which status code should I use?

Tags: http, redirect, http-status-codes

Http status 302 is status for temporary redirections. I think we can use this status for my purpose. I google and see someone use 303, Not 302. How about your ideas? Thanks!

Comment: It shouldn't matter really, but see this question for more info:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129076/after-a-post-should-i-do-a-302-or-a-303-redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking for examples or tutorials that show HTTPS redirections with IIS and URL Rewrite, you'll find all variants of [redirectType](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Redirect_action):

- [301 - Permanent](http://www.surfingsuccess.com/asp/iis-url-rewrite.html)
- [302 - Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028223/url-rewrite-on-iis-from-http-to-https-is-not-working)
- [303 - See Other](http://www.jppinto.com/2010/03/automatically-redirect-http-requests-to-https-on-iis7-using-url-rewrite-2-0/)
- [307 - Temporary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467558/iis7-rewrite-module-not-redirecting-ssl-to-non-ssl-page)

When you like clients to use HTTPS the next time, use Permanent. If you're trying the redirection for a while and you're not sure if you want it to be permanent, use Temporary.

Sort of the same question is answered by more people here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22268/when-redirecting-from-http-to-https-in-a-shop-site-which-status-code-should-i-u